# Как сделать репорт в виде скриншота во время тестирования на node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, mocha, crossbrowsertesting

Всем привет! Интересует тестирование веб-приложений.
Хотелось бы при запуске автотеста, автоматически делался скриншот действия в какую то папку.
Использую я node.js и тестраннер mocha.  Читал, то что mocha может делать скрины, но как?
Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: например вот [пакет](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mochawesome-screenshots)

Comment: @Grundy "ответы в ответы!" =)